# Threads, the eternal cycle, asyncio

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, python-asyncio

I need to log in to multiple accounts at the same time, and I was advised to create a stream. How can I do this?

```
def startChecking(login, password):
    session = startSession()
    logIn(session, login, password)
    while True:
        lastData = findAll(session)
        time.sleep(5)
        lastChat = findAll(session)
        if lastData == lastChat:
            gg = 0
        else:
            print(f'{login}', lastChat['userSms'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # There will be a for loop that will take the login and password
    session = startSession()
    logIn(session, 'login', 'password')
    while True:
        lastData = findAll(session)
        time.sleep(5)
        lastChat = findAll(session)
        if lastData == lastChat:
            gg = 0
        else:
            print('login\nNew message:', lastChat['userSms'])
```

The code will be something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # There will be a for loop that will take the login and password
    allAcc = list(collectionFunPay.find())
    for i in range(0, len(allAcc)):
        print(allAcc[i]['login'], allAcc[i]['password'])
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop) # An eternal cycle that must be performed continuously
        loop.run_until_complete(startChecking(allAcc[i]['login'], allAcc[i]['password']))
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well
I figured out how to do it
Here is my code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    allAcc = list(collectionFunPay.find())
    for i in range(0, len(allAcc)):
        print(allAcc[i]['login'], allAcc[i]['password'])
        t = Thread(target=startChecking, args=(allAcc[i]['login'], allAcc[i]['password']))
        t.start()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).